# Spring boot - method 'POST' is not supported (multipart/form-data)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I'm trying to send through multipart/form-data  a post request from my products controller, where I upload a file of images and information of my product in json

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {
    final ProductService productService;
    final CategoryService categoryService;
    final ProductMapper productMapper;
    final S3Client s3Client;

    private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    public ProductController(ProductService productService, ProductMapper productMapper, CategoryService categoryService, S3Client s3Client) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.productMapper = productMapper;
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }
    @PostMapping(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestPart("productDto") @Valid ProductDto productDto, @RequestPart(value = "file")MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (productService.existsByProduct(productDto.getProduct())) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Product already exists!");
            }
            ProductModel productModel = productMapper.toProductModel(productDto);
            CategoryModel categoryModel = categoryService.findById(productDto.getProductCategory().getCategory_id())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Category not found"));
            productModel.setProductCategory(categoryModel);

            String fileName = "/products/images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + file.getOriginalFilename();

            s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest
                            .builder()
                            .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                            .key(fileName)
                            .build(),
                        software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody.fromString("Testing java sdk"));
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(productService.save(productModel));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Cannot create product. Check if the fields sent in your request are correct.");
        }
    }
```

in my postman I'm sending it like this, and getting the error 405
[image]

In my console I am getting the error:

```
Request method 'POST' is not supported]
```

I don't understand why since I am sending a postMapping

updated error in postman:

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "stackTrace": [
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "from",
            "fileName": "UnrecognizedPropertyException.java",
            "lineNumber": 61,
            "nativeMethod": false,
            "className": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException"
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "handleUnknownProperty",
            "fileName": "DeserializationContext.java",
            "lineNumber": 1132,
            "nativeMethod": false,
            "className": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext"
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "handleUnknownProperty",
            "fileName": "StdDeserializer.java",
            "lineNumber": 2202,
            "nativeMethod": false,
            "className": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer"
        }, ...
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know what else I can add, it's just that the error and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: If only the `@PostMapping` is relevant, remove all the other handler methods. Does the body of the method matter? If not, reduce it to the bare minimum. Provide your `main` method where you start the `SpringApplication`. Reduce it to the bare minimum to reproduce your error as well.

Comment: First of all `@PostMapping(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)` is not correct please fix this and check your code again. It must be `@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)`

Comment: @G.Guvenal That's likely the answer. `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` is a String. `@PostMapping` default `value` element is a synonym for path. So their `@PostMapping` is registered to handle a path equal to the value of `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`, which obviously isn't `product`.

Comment: now the error is "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported]"

Comment: @JunqRal please edit your question with new error and screenshots.

Comment: Check your html form tag attribute !!!   enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your     `@PostMapping(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)`
because putting the media type there will actually map the URL to `/product/multipart/form-data` and not `/product/`

change it to this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

also, you need to update the method signature to something like this (Change @RequestPart to @RequestParam)

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestParam("productDto") String jsonString, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       ProductDto productDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ProductDto.class);
    }
```

and make sure you have the relevant dependencies commons-fileupload and commons-io

also I recomemend when Uploading set a maximum upload size for the file you can do it like this:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024 * 1024 * 5); // 5 MB
    return resolver;
}
```

and then in postman call `http://localhost:8078/product/`

A second solution you can create the suitable converter in Spring:
the solution is like

```
public class ProductDtoConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<ProductDto> {
    
    public ProductDtoConverter() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ProductDto.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected ProductDto readInternal(Class<? extends ProductDto> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        String productDtoString = IOUtils.toString(inputMessage.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(productDtoString, ProductDto.class);
    }
}
```

and in you AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ProductDtoConverter productDtoConverter() {
        return new ProductDtoConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: now the error is " Content-Type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported"

Comment: I updated my answer change RequestPart to RequestParam

Comment: @JunqRal did it work? if anything else put your error here

Comment: ok, I put the "/" at the end of the link, and it returned the error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.ProductDto'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.ProductDto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Comment: now we have to deal a separate issue which is conversion: you have two solution change either change ProductDto in the Post method to Sting and convert it later 

public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestParam("productDto") String jsonString, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ProductDto productDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ProductDto.class);

Comment: I did the first solution, and now I'm falling into the exception of the post. I decided to put the exception to return to know what's going on, and I got some stuff in my postman and I updated the question (I got more stuff like this, but the text is so big that it doesn't fit in the question)

Comment: UnrecognizedPropertyException

Comment: use https://pastebin.com/ to print the whole exception

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/Owx9Bsc

Comment: "originalMessage": "Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value",
    "suppressed": [],
    "localizedMessage": "Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: (String)\"{\"product\": \"iPhone 13 270 gb\", \"brand\": \"Apple\", \"description: \"nada a declarar\", \"price\": 8500, \"stock\": 56, \"productCategory\": {\"category_id\": \"6fc186b1-c97a-49c9-ba6a-2da8e38e53d8\"}}\"; line: 1, column: 67]"

Comment: Do you have knowledge about amazon s3? aws

Comment: yes I have some knowledge, you can create a new question and tag me in it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653867/amazon-aws-error-with-s3-bucket-not-existing-spring-boot

Comment: Could you help me ?

Comment: Error for the second solution: `Class 'ProductDtoConverter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'writeInternal(T, HttpOutputMessage)' in 'AbstractHttpMessageConverter'`