# Amazon aws error with s3 bucket not existing (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, api, amazon-s3

I'm developing a product registration api in spring boot, and in my post method I send an image upload via multipart/form-data, along with a json with my product's dto. As you can see:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {
    final ProductService productService;
    final CategoryService categoryService;
    final ProductMapper productMapper;
    final S3Client s3Client;

    private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    public ProductController(ProductService productService, ProductMapper productMapper, CategoryService categoryService, S3Client s3Client) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.productMapper = productMapper;
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestParam("productDto") String jsonString, @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ProductDto productDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ProductDto.class);

            if (productService.existsByProduct(productDto.getProduct())) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Product already exists!");
            }
            ProductModel productModel = productMapper.toProductModel(productDto);
            CategoryModel categoryModel = categoryService.findById(productDto.getProductCategory().getCategory_id())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Category not found"));
            productModel.setProductCategory(categoryModel);

            String fileName = "/products/images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + file.getOriginalFilename();

            s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest
                            .builder()
                            .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                            .key(fileName)
                            .build(),
                        software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody.fromString("Testing java sdk"));
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(productService.save(productModel));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I am having problems making the request from my postman

```
    "localizedMessage": "The specified bucket does not exist (Service: S3, Status Code: 404, Request ID: ZZ27F9CNNTG2RTPR, Extended Request ID:
```

Despite the message, checking amazon aws I can see that indeed my bucket exists and has the same name as the one I configured in my application. This is amazonConfig

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

@Configuration
public class AmazonConfig {
    private final String AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";
    private final String BUCKET_NAME = "productstockimages";

    @Value("${aws.accessKeyId}")
    private String accessKeyId;

    @Value("${aws.secretAccessKey}")
    private String secretAccessKey;

    @Bean
    public S3Client s3Client() {
        AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        return S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.of(AWS_REGION))
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                .build();
    }
}
```

In my secretKey and in my AccessKey, I configured in properties with the keys of my authorized IAM user from the amazon aws console.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above references **AWS SDK for Java V1** - which is not recommended to use anymore. See the SDK page here for Version information:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples

Rather then looking into the AWS S3 Service Guide that contains V1 code, now refer to the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) that uses the latest SDK version - which for Java is AWS SDK for Java V2.

[image]

For AWS SDK for Java V2 examples, see:

[Code examples for Amazon S3 using AWS SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_s3_code_examples.html)

I have used V2 in many Spring Boot projects and there are no issues working with S3 operations. So to use S3 Java functionality in Spring boot, upgrade to V2 - which is best practice.

**UPDATE ON A POSSIBLE ISSUE**

I am looking at your code much closer. I see this issue in your controller:

**private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();**

**You are changing your bucket name with a time stamp**. Then you call **putObject()** and reference that bucket name with a timestamp. Unless you created a bucket on the fly with that name (and I do not see that logic), that bucket does not exist and you get an exception.

SO you have 2 choices:

- keep the bucket name static so you know it exists.
- or if you have to keep a timestamp for a bucket, then use the V2 API and a waiter to create a bucket before calling **putObject()**. Then you can reference the bucket name with the timestamp. To learn how to create a new bucket with a waiter using V2, see the Create Bucket example here. Notice the user of a waiter. This approach will create a new bucket for each request. I personally would use a static bucket name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_s3_code_examples.html

Comment: Well, apparently the javav2/ page it's unavaliable

Comment: See https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2

Comment: I don't understand, the link in this documentation to download the sdk takes me to the amazon aws website for the java sdk, but it is precisely this version that I installed

Comment: This is my version: 2.20.14

Comment: See my update - you are referencing a bucket with a time stamp that most likely does not exist

Answer (score 0):

To upload your data (photos, videos, documents, etc.) to Amazon S3, you must first create an S3 bucket in one of the AWS Regions, a bucket is a container for objects stored in Amazon S3.

You need to make sure the bucket you're using already exists

use this condition to make sure the bucket already exists before uploading a file to S3:

```
if (s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)) {
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType(contentType);
            metadata.setContentLength(stream.available());

            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, stream, metadata));
        } else {
            log.warn("AWS S3 '{}' Bucket does not exist", bucketName);
             s3client.createBucket(bucketName);
        }
```

if `s3client.createBucket(bucketName);` throws an exception that means you're not allowed to create a bucket use this documentation to create one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/create-bucket-overview.html

If you don't have access at all, you need to talk to your AWS admin to create one for you.

Also don't create a bucket each time like this

```
private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```

just use one for different kind of APP

```
private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts-app1-dev"
```

so you don't create a bucket each time you run the application

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol 'doesBucketExistsV2'"

Comment: In case I already have a bucket, I already checked it on amazon aws

Comment: the issue is here too

private final String BUCKET_NAME = "awstockproducts" + System.currentTimeMillis();

Bucket name change each time in the controller

Comment: you probably using an older SDK, i updated my code

Comment: In mine there are no options with "doesExists" in relation to s3Client. I am using version:
 2.20.14

Comment: yeah use that I updated my answer

Comment: "doesBucketExist" too lol